# Strange result when calling function with iteration over elements of a list

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I defined a very simple function for the Birthday Problem:

```
from math import comb, factorial
import numpy as np

def birthday(k):
    return 1-((factorial(k)*comb(365,k))/(365**k))
```

The function works, since `k=23` gives:

```
[in] birthday(23)
[out] 0.5072972343239854
```

I want to iterate over a list with `k` going from 1 to 50 and save the probability outcomes to a list `prob`, like this:

```
klist=np.arange(1,51)
prob=[]
for k in klist:
    prob.append(birthday(k))
```

For k=1 up to k=7, there is no problem, but from `k=8` onwards, suddenly the output doesn't make sense anymore with very large negative values. What am I doing wrong here? (showing output for k=1 to 10)

`[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 ]`

`[0.0, 0.002739726027397249, 0.008204165884781345, 0.016355912466550326, 0.02713557369979358, 0.040462483649111536, 0.056235703095975365, -203.08817475498518, -20769.916905383445, -11786425.811859423]`

However, just running:
`[in] birthday(10)`
Gives the correct:
`[out] 0.11694817771107768`

Comment: I think this has to do with the differences between numpy's int32 and python's int. Because if you do `prob.append(birthday(int(k)))` it works fine. So maybe look in to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is somehow in using this:

```
klist=np.arange(1,51)
```

That makes k an `numpy.int32` for every call to `birthday`. And if you try this:

```
print(birthday(np.int32(10)))
```

You'll find that has the same problem.

This works though:

```
from math import comb, factorial
import numpy as np


def birthday(k):
    return 1-((factorial(k)*comb(365,k))/(365**k))


prob=[]
for k in range(51):
    prob.append(birthday(k))
```

A 32-bit integer appears to be not large enough to hold the values `birthday()` computes and it would appear it overflows.

Comment: Great find. Indeed, it even makes an numpy.int64 (when I call type(klist[8]). Can I make a list with just int? Thanks a lot!
Edit: I created the klist with integers in the for loop by adding a line klist.append(k)

Comment: Yes, simply using `klist = list(range(51))` would be a list with a Python `int`, which has no real limit to its size (although performance is limited of course). In your example you don't really need a list, you can just `for` over the `range` generator as I indicated, but perhaps you need the list elsewhere in your code as well, then my suggestion should work.

Comment: Indeed, thanks again!

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the checkmark next to the answer, so that the question no longer appears unanswered